# Increment version in a certain file and commit back to git

Tags: git, awk, sed

[image]

I have two index.html files, containing properties like `rev=a=0.1`, `bust=b=0.1`.

In the first file, I want to increase `rev=a` by +1 resulting in `0.2`. In the second file, I want to increase `rev=a` and `bust=b` by +1, resulting in `0.2`. This increment should happen for every build by incrementing only number but not any other code, not even quotations, and commit back to git.

I heard that sed and awk commands can be used. Can someone please help me what should be the commands?

I have tried these commands in Jenkins integrated with Git through build step shell. Git has these files.

```
sed -r -i 's/(.*)(\?rev=)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' src/main/webapp/index.html
sed -r -i 's/(.*)(\?bust=)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' src/main/webapp/index.html
sed -r -i 's/(.*)(\?rev=)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' src/main/webapp/common/index.html

git status
git add -A
git commit -am 'Updated Version Number for next build to $NEW_VERSION'
git push origin HEAD:origin
```

But for example, if `rev` and `bust` is `15.06`, it's getting increased to `16.06` instead of `15.07` by this command. Also it's stripping the `"` quotes for that line.

I can make it commit for every build.
I want to try only shell commands here !!!

Please find the updated commands and results

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at how sed and awk work? Are you wanting these to increment automatically? How do you define a build? Do you mean with every commit?

Comment: I have modified the question, please provide your valuable reply !!   @llion

Comment: If this is to create a build number it will break badly when you start working in multiple branches.  Just use the commit id to identify the build.

Comment: I would recommend instead you have a single file with the version number in it and everything that needs the version reads that. Rather than trying to modify static files, generate them from templates.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

if you're not incrementing by 0.1, for input test file

```
rev=a=0.1
bust=b=13.1
other lines
```

running

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1~/^(rev|bust)$/{$NF+=0.1}1' file
```

will give

```
rev=a=0.2
bust=b=13.2
other lines
```

Or, perhaps you want to increment the value after decimal point by one, for the input file

```
rev=a=0.1
bust=b=13.1
other lines
rev=a=1.9
bust=b=13.99
```

running

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} $1~/^(rev=a=|bust=b=)/{$NF+=1}1' file
```

will generate

```
rev=a=0.2
bust=b=13.2
other lines
rev=a=1.10
bust=b=13.100
```

Answer (score 0):

### You aren't matching what you think

Your sed expression doesn't line up with what you are trying to match.

You want to change `?rev=14.06` to `?rev=14.07`. But you aren't capturing that at all. Your match is currently working like this.

```
s/(.*)(\?rev=)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge
       ^       ^       ^
       |       |       |
       |       |       +-- here you start matching ".06" -- [\4]
       |       +---------- here you match the "14" -------- [\3]
       +------------------ here you match the "?rev=" ----- [\2]
```

As shown above, you match `?rev=`as you expect. But next you match *only* the digits `14`. That's because you forgot to include `.` as part of the matching class. And lastly, the wildcard pickup `.*` matches `.06` and everything following.

Therefore, when you add 1 to the `\3` match, it increments from 14 to 15. And then to 16, 17, and so on.

Even if you had matched the way it appears you were thinking, that is, had you matched `14.06` as `\3`, adding 1 would not move to `14.07`, it would be `15.07`. And that's if sed even supports floating-point math, which I'm not sure it does.

You probably want something like this instead:

```
s/(.*)(\?(rev|bust)=[0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\4+1))\5"/ge
       ^                      ^
       |                      |
       |                      +----- this matches "06" -- [\4]
       +--------------------- this matches "?rev=14." --- [\2]
```

Now when you add 1 to the `\4` match, you've only matched the part of the number after the decimal. So from `6` you will get `7`, `8`, and so on.

In this case it matched `14.06`, but this should work the same to turn `13.1` into `13.2`, and so on.

So your command will be:

```
sed -r -i 's/(.*)(\?(rev|bust)=[0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\4+1))\5"/ge' {filename}
```

### There's a leading zero that will get dropped

This is more or less cosmetic, but note that if you match on "14.06" as shown in your example, this will be turned into "14.7" if you are using `$(( ))` math and the `echo` command.

### Using echo is dropping the quotes

Your replacement section in the sed command is using `echo "..."` to create the new text. When you pass in double-quotes to that, it will get confused. The command you end up running is something like this.

```sh
echo "<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/constants.js?rev=14.7"></script>"
```

If you look at where the quotes are, that is sort of like running this:

```sh
printf "<script type="
printf "text/javascript"
printf " src="
printf "scripts/constants.js?rev=14.7"
echo "></script>"
```

Using Linux `/bin/sh`, the output is like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript src=scripts/constants.js?rev=14.7></script>
```

Honestly, you're lucky that it worked out so none of the `<` or `>` were outside the quotes, or you'd have had a redirection error happen.

To fix that, you can just use single quotes in the HTML file. Then no double quotes will be passed to the `echo` command, and `sed` should not strip the quotes.

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/constants.js?rev=14.06'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/main.js?rev=14.06'></script>
```

Now, the outer double-quotes will wrap everything properly and the single-quotes in your HTML will be preserved.

Comment: Somehow that command is not working, its doing nothing @Dan                        sed -r -i 's/(.*)(\?(rev|bust)=[0-9+]\.)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' src/main/webapp/index.html     the properties are not at all changing

Comment: @ReddyNiihar Sorry, I updated the answer earlier without actually testing the new version. There were 3 bugs in it. I have fixed and re-tested and it works now. The `sed` command at the end of the first section. It assumes your file is using single quotes, not double quotes, on the relevant lines.

Comment: @ReddyNiihar Just remove the `\?` and it will match `rev=` and `bust=` without the `?`.

Comment: Superb...It worked!!! @Dan you are awesome, thanks for being patient and helping out..You have a good one